# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export', but module 'import' still works

Tags: javascript, import, export, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I'm confused here. I'm a newbie.

**index.html**

```html
  <script src="appearance.js"></script>
  <script src="table-gen.js" type="module"></script>
```

**appearance.js**

```js
  export const genModBtn = document.querySelector('.gen-mod-btn-container button');
```

**table-gen.js**

```js
  import { genModBtn } from "./appearance.js";
  console.log(genModBtn);
```

Why am I getting this 'Unexpected token' if all seems to be working fine?

The `import { genModBtn } from "./appearance.js";` seems to be working fine since `console.log(genModBtn)` is  working too.

I've tried to remove `export` from `export const genModBtn = document.querySelector('.gen-mod-btn-container button')`, but without it, all stops working and it still log a different error.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `<script src="appearance.js"></script>` is incorrect and unnecessary. Remove it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should mark both of them as modules:

```js
<script src="appearance.js" type="module></script>
<script src="table-gen.js" type="module"></script>
```

The rest of the syntax seems fine. You can also use global variables like this:

```js
// appearance.js
window.genModBtn = document.querySelector('.gen-mod-btn-container button');

// table-gen.js
console.log(genModBtn);
```

Comment: Thank you, Juan. That solves my problem! And thanks for the tip too.